# Radial functions and differential operators

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry

i have the following problem.

Consider $f(\frac{|x|^2}{2})$ a radial function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}$. Then my book says
that 
$$\Delta f-\langle x,\nabla f\rangle$$
is basically the same as
$2xf''(x)+(1-2x)f'(x)$

Can someone elaborate on that or give me an example for $f$ to understand this?

Comment: Your problem (assuming this is how it was given to you) seems to use a very confusing notation. Which is not rare coming from experienced teacher who forget to be sensitive to students comprehension. Please take a look if noting is missing on the question you are asking. Try to tell if $x$ is meant to be a scalar or a vector. If it's a scalar, then $<x,\nabla f>$ is making no sense. If it's a vector then $2xf''(x)$ should not be written like this.

Comment: If all this is the original problem, then I can answer explaining why that does not make sense, but despite trying I couldn't figure out by myself what is assumed to make this proposition valid.